# Why csv file doesnt show special characters in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv, idatareader

I have this code used on my application to convert xls file to csv file.

```
Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
excelReader.Close();
result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
string csvfile = "";
int row_no = 0;
int ind = 0;

while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvfile += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + ",";
    }

    row_no++;
    csvfile += "\n";
}

output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/test.csv");
newOutput = Path.GetFileName(output);
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false, Encoding.Unicode);
csv.Write(csvfile);
csv.Close();
csv.Dispose();
```

It worked fine but csv doesn't show cell values correctly.
See below images and I have pasted my code as well.
What can I change on this code to fix this?

This is the exported csv and it shows like this

[image]

I have tried replacing on my code, but I don't have changes

```
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false, Encoding.ASCII);  
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false, Encoding.Unicode);  
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Remove all of the dataset stuff and show us the [mcve] where you write a hard-coded string to the CSV. Keep it to 10 lines or less, so it is easy for us to repro.

Comment: also don't open it in Excel since there's a lot of auto "guessing" done to convert certain strings as Excel deems them to be "correct", use notepad to check raw text.

Comment: @kshkarin actually if I open the csv file using Notepad the characters are correct, I don't understand...

Comment: What tool are you using to view the CSV?  The tool may be using the wrong encoding or a different FONT.  So results are probably correct but the tool you are using to view the results is creating the issue.

Comment: @jdweng for view the CSV I use Office 365 Excel

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Encoding.Unicode` (which is **actually** UTF-16LE) instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Unrelated tip: you should use `StringBuilder` instead of using the `+=` operator inside a loop to concatenate strings, because that will cause excessive string allocation in .NET.

Comment: ASCII encoding will remove non printable characters.  iso-8859-1 may be the wrong encoding as well as Unicode.  If you do not want the data to change use UTF-8 like Dai suggested.

Comment: @jdweng I have use `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `UTF-8`, nothing change... :(

Comment: Try "Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))", does that work for you?

Comment: @MarioZ thank you MarioZ! Using `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))` the csv file show cell values correctly! :)